# Hide column when exporting OBIEE report to Excel

Tags: export-to-excel, obiee

In an Oracle BI 10g report, some of the columns are hidden with CSS: `display:none`.
But when I try to export the report to Excel file, the hidden columns appear. I tried with `mso-hide:all;` in the CSS, but it did not hide any columns, because the table is into another table. Do you have any ideas how to hide these columns from Oracle BI Analytics in order not to appear when exporting the report to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a separate logical table with only columns you need to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the edit view button in the analysis tab.
*-Click on More Options button in the appropiate column.
*-Click on hidden.

The concerned column will be hidden in the analyis as well as in the excel file.